# Develop Angular application with amexio

Tags: angular, webpack

I use `amexio` component to help me develop the application,but when the theme is already set and command `ng` serve , the console in visual studio print Error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.cssModule
build failed: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
at Object.isAbsolute (path.js:460:5)
at Promise.all.paths.map.file (C:\Users\han\Documents\myAngular\practice2\node_modules\postcss-import\index.js:193:24)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Promise.resolve.then.paths (C:\Users\han\Documents\myAngular\practice2\node_modules\postcss-import\index.js:192:15)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
@ ./src/styles.css 4:14-138
@ multi ./src/styles.css
```

When I save styles.css and ng serve is work,but it's still print the message like above message with WARNING.
How should I manage this problem ? use webpack or cssloader?

```
@angular/cli": "1.6.7"

@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0"

amexio-ng-extensions": "^4.2.0"
```

Comment: it is just WARNING ignore it. AMEXIO team is working on it and get back to you

Comment: this issue is resolved in new version of amexio 4.2.8 .Please checkout